# CDN files url need to redirect 301 or 302?

Tags: node.js, redirect, cdn, cache-control, googlebot

I create CDN server with NodeJs
For cache controlling, I keep last file versions in Server DB.
From client, I request to main file name, without version: `"cdn.xxx.com/file.js"`
Then in server I find file version and redirect 302 to: `"cdn.xxx.com/file.js?v=3.2"`

these are my questions:
1) As file versions might change multiple times in week, so i redirect 302, not 301 (permanent). Did I do the right thing?
2) looks like **Google-bot** has problem with this redirection, most of my links fails with `"Redirection error"` in Search Console Live Test. Any idea why?

Test link: https://cdn.boqr.at/ADMdtpDrv

Comment: Status code 302 is obsolete. It's been replaced by status codes 303 and 307. In your case, I think code 303 should be appropriate.

Comment: P.S.: if Google-bot is giving you problems cause of the redirects, you could also avoid redirecting. I mean: when someone requests page `cdn.xxx.com/file.js` they get directly the latest version of the file, without redirecting the user to another page.

Comment: @LucaPolito tnx for responding. to increasing site speed, I rather use browser caching, so to force browser use latest version i redirect to new url. if i always give user the latest file, i should set 'Cache-Control' to 'no-cache', because as you know, browser file caching is base on file url.